# Skip few records(items) from lists in sharepoint online using JQuery Rest API

Tags: jquery, performance, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am fetching some records and display in list view but I want to implement "Load More" functionality.
I will fetch 5 records on page load and then 5 more records on load more button and keep on.

I have tried **$skip** but that is not working at "item" level which is working only at "list" level.

I tried "**$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE%26p_ID=5**" but it skips first from 5 Id and in my Query $filter is with "StartDate" of item rather than ID.

```
https://mytest.sharepoint.com/sites/products/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ProductsList')/items?&$select=ID,Title,startdate,enddate,Created&$filter=(startdate le datetime '2021-03-03T12:00:00Z' and enddate ge datetime '2021-03-03T12:00:00Z')&$orderby=startdate desc,Title&$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE%26p_ID=5&$top=5
```

Is there any way to achieve this ?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue and solution is here :
[SharePoint online - 'Load More' button click event to show more items using PnPjs](https://chand-jogani.blogspot.com/2021/03/SharePoint-online-Load-More-button-click-event-with-PnPjs.html)